# SOAP NTLM login using .net core 2.1.300 failed on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, wcf, soap, asp.net-core

I recently need to use .net core to do SOAP NTLM login.. to my horror.. I realized ,net core does not come with SOAP support.. fumbling around, I came across SOAPCore on nuget package which has SOAP middleware for .net core. My console app interfacing to .net core 2.1 SDK tries to do NTLM login. Below is the codes, very simple.. it's trying to login to Milestone VMS.

<----------codes--------------->

int MAX_BUFFERSIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

string strURL = "http://192.168.51.207/ServerAPI/ServerCommandService.asmx";

BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

httpBinding.MaxBufferSize = MAX_BUFFERSIZE;

httpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MAX_BUFFERSIZE;

httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;

httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;   //changed Ntlm to Windows also don't help

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(strURL);

var factory = new ChannelFactory(httpBinding, endpoint);

CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();

NetworkCredential ntcc = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");

cc.Add(strURL, 80, "ntlm", ntcc);

factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = cc.GetCredential(strURL, 80, "ntlm");

var client = factory.CreateChannel();

Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

LoginInfo lo = client.Login(guid, "");

Console.Write("\ntoken=" + lo.Token);

ConfigurationInfo config = client.GetConfiguration(lo.Token);

... //do something

client.Loguout(guid, lo.Token); //logout

<-------------end of code segment------------>

Now, running this in Windows 10 works fine.. it's able to login and get the info needed.. but funny thing is when it runs on Linux.. I installed BASH for Windows 10 and it's Ubuntu 18.04, and have installed .net core 2.1.300..  it gave an http code 401 exception:  "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate, Ntlm'."

I've previously read on Stackoverflow about something quite similar and it was said that .net core 2.1 would resolve it.. I'm already using 2.1.300. Is it still not resolved? or am I doing something wrong?

Another question I have pertaining to this, the "ServerCommandServiceSoap" interface is generated using svcutil.exe from the wsdl file provided by Milestone in their SDK. Now, what is the difference between svcutil.exe and wsdl.exe? I noticed that the proxy class generated isn't the same usi ng these two tools.. using svcutil.exe has an interface class with dependencies on System.ServiceModel, while using wsdl.exe has no interface class and depends on System.Web.Services which is not available in .net core. why is it different when they are ran against the same wsdl document?

Can someone please enlighten me on this? thanks a lot..  :)